2 parts get selected
When i select a part of the mesh another part is selected as well. When 2 parts is selected it doesn't work to sculpt the part i try to select. This goes away after moving around modes a couple of times. What makes things as this happen? I am thinking the mesh will screw up later so say how i keep it from happening.


It's not clear what you are doing. Please be more specific with more screenshots maybe? or describe the problem more in detail.
